# Relative frequency

Tags: probability

In a given scenario where two fair dice are thrown:

what is the probability of the second roll being higher than the first?

I can think of two ways to resolve this problem;

1- listing the possible outcomes and obtaining the relative frequencies
2- 1/6 *(5/6*4/6*3/6*2/6*1/6) divided by 36

however, is there a more mathematically rigorous way of obtaining the answer?

i.e. 15/36

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $\mathsf P(X>Y) = \mathsf P(Y<X)$ by symmetry, and $\mathsf P(X>Y)+\mathsf P(Y>X) + \mathsf P(X=Y) = 1$ by Law of Total Probability.

Hence $\mathsf P(Y>X) = \frac{1}{2}\Big(1-\mathsf P(X=Y)\Big)$

**Reason:** There are only three possibilities: that both die roll the same result, or that one or the other is greater.   As both die rolls are independent, the probability that the first is greater than the second is equal to the probability that the second is greater than the first.   Thus the probability that the second die rolls greater than the first is equal to half the probability that both die do *not* roll the same result.

Can you evaluate this probability now?

Comment: Ok, thank you Graham.